# First off-topic close reason text should be updated for new Stack Overflow phrasing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, on-topic-definition

Recently, Stack Overflow [changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385331/mcvexit-redux-i-dont-need-a-milkshake-to-know-when-ive-missed-the-mark) the "mcve" (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example) phrase to "mre" (Minimal Reproducible Example).  While the old links still work, the new canonical link is to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The text for the first off-topic close reason currently reads

> Questions asking for **assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code** are off-topic here. These can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if they include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question (see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Can this be updated to refer to the new phrasing, "Minimal, Reproducible Example" with the updated URL?  (And fix the "Stack Overflow" link to use https?)

The updated text would be:

> Questions asking for **assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code** are off-topic here. These can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if they include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question (see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: would be funny if our reason text was changed to use "reprex" and linked to that [infamous MSO announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384994/839601)

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but it looks like we need to make a new close reason and get approval from a different mod. I'm sure we can get this done in the near future, though.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I've made the new close reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Harvey made the close reason and I've approved it, putting it in place of the other close reason. This should be resolved - thanks for the heads up.